# write.table in R writing more rows than in the dataframe

Tags: r

I am working with a very large dataframe (34236 rows, 530 columns) `FINAL.Merged`. When I tried to write it, it creates a .txt file with 18 more lines (i.e., 34254 rows) than it is in the dataframe.

I tried to replicate this error with other dataframes, but did not get such error. I never encountered this issue before and find it very unusual. Does anyone have any clue as to why?
This is the code I am using:

```
write.table(FINAL.Merged, "Pediatric_cancer_survivors.txt", quote = FALSE, row.names = FALSE, sep = "\t")
```

**UPDATE:** Just so it would be helpful to others, this is how I fixed it:

```
library("dplyr")
FINAL.Merged <- FINAL.Merged %>%
      mutate_if(is.character, trimws)
```

My dataframes were read from SAS data and had whitespaces. After trimming the whitespace, I no longer have this problem.

Comment: Embedded line-breaks inside a cell in SAS I'm guessing?

Comment: I don't see why extra white space (spaces) would introduce lines.  But if some of the character strings contained actual end of line characters then that would definitely generate more lines written in the file than just the number of observations in the dataframe.  Might be less destructive to just remove those specific characters.